# Cross-platform dockerized `rootfs` builder very slow without `-privileged`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-platform

I am trying to build an Orange Pi 5 (aarch64) image on my x86 machine with Gentoo.
For that, I created a [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/shSi4sAD) of Ubuntu 22.04 docker image to run the image [build script](https://github.com/orangepi-xunlong/orangepi-build) provided.

What I noticed is that when I ran the script without `--privileged`, the build script would complain things like `Unable to mount {/proc,/sys,...}` and the `qemu-binfmt` (which I guess is for binary translation) became **extremely slow**.

After some digging I found that the build script invokes `chroot`, enters the newly-built rootfs, and performs some configuration (with `qemu-binfmt`). Some materials online suggest that `--privileged` should be added for `docker` in such a use case.

So, I added the `--privilege`, and both the complaints and the slowness were gone.

My question is that are these two phenomena connected? Is the slowness caused by the failure of mounting `/sys` and `/proc`? Does the `qemu-binfmt` translation relate to any of these?

Anything would be helpful, like ideas of how to do experiments to verify the connection.

I also did some research on my own, but haven't found something too useful on this matter. Thanks in advance.